# SQL Select with hours as rows and various zones as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a query that I need help on:

```
Select convert(char(2), IncTime, 108)  AS Hours, ISNULL(COUNT(IncNo),0) as 'Zone1'
From tblClosedCases
where IncDate between '01/01/2017' and '01/07/2017' and Zone = 'Zone1'
Group by convert(char(2), IncTime, 108)
```

tblClosedCases contains, of course, which I am using as my rows. tblClosedCases also has a field of Zone. The current DB I am using has values of Zone1, Zone2, Zone3, Zone4.

The field Zone values can be changed by the user to be anything from Z1 to ABC123 and can vary from 2 zones to 20 zones.

Is there a way to create a select query so that no matter the field value or the number of fields I get results like this with the column names as the values the customer has entered?

```
Hours   Zone1   Zone2   Zone3
00       22      5       15
01       34      21      14
02       41      9       9
```

etc.

I know you'll need more info but I'm not sure what else that may be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit to include sql-server. It would be on SQL 2008 R2 and above.

Answer (score 0):

(should be a comment, but I don't have reputation sufficient to comment)

What do you mean by the statement quoted below -- where does Z1 to ABC123 fit in your example, are those Zone names?  Will different table have different numbers of columns with different names?  If so, you'll need dynamic sql, and it will matter what database engine you  are using.

The heart of  what you're doing in a pivot query, and a typical way to do it is like

```
sum(case when zone='Zone 1' then Incno else 0 end) as 'Zone 1', 
sum(case when zone='Zone 2' then Incno else 0 end) as 'Zone 2'. . . 
 sum(case when zone='Zone N' then Incno else 0 end) as 'Zone N',
```

using grouping like you show.  But that relies on knowing the names of the columns an how many there are when you write the query.

> The field Zone values can be changed by the user to be anything from Z1 to ABC123 and can vary from 2 zones to 20 zones.

If you will have varying columns from a single chunk of  code, it'll be dynamic sql, and you should add tag 'dynamic-sql' and a tag for your database product(s)

Comment: Edited to include dynamic-sql as a tag. And yes, the "Z1, ABC123" could be zones names. But again, that may vary depending upon the customer. I know I could build a static query but 1 customer may have just 2 zones whereas another may have 10 zones.